# Powershell Script to Set Quota

Tags: powershell, quota

We are planning to apply quotas on our site collections of about 60 which are already created in our web application . i thought of achieving that using power shell but we are facing a small problem which is in that 60 site collections i can keep quotas on only 40 site collections as the other 20 will grow rapidly everyday.The only way that i can see the difference is that the managed path of these site collections are different .can anyone please tell me how can i set the quota on a site collection only if it has a manged path 'projects'and leave those which have managed path called 'communities'

Thanks

My Code Up to now

```
   function CreateQuotaTemplate ($Name, $MaxLevelMB, $WarnLevelMB)
    {
    $quotaTemplate = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPQuotaTemplate
    $quotaTemplate.Name = $Name
    $quotaTemplate.StorageMaximumLevel = ($MaxLevelMB*1024)*1024
    $quotaTemplate.StorageWarningLevel = ($WarnLevelMB*1024)*1024
    $contentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
    $contentService.QuotaTemplates.Add($quotaTemplate)
    $contentService.Update()
    }

    CreateQuotaTemplate –Name “Power” –MaxLevelMB 300 –WarnLevelMB 280



 # Replace all site collection quotas in a web application with a new template
$TemplateName = "Power"
$WebApplicationUrl = "http://myportal/"

$contentService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService
$quotaTemplate = $contentService.QuotaTemplates[$TemplateName]
$webApplication = Get-SPWebApplication $WebApplicationUrl
$webApplication.Sites | ForEach-Object { try { $_.Quota = $quotaTemplate; } finally { $_.Dispose(); } }
```

Comment: Can you post the script you have so far?

Comment: Hi Dave i just edited my question and added my code

Comment: This looks like it only sets the quota on the root site collection.  Where is your code to iterate through the other site collections in the web application?

Comment: Sorry Dave i added the wrong function now i added the bulk function..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside your try {} block, you might need something like this to check the URL and only apply the quota to the ones you want.

```
if ($_.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("/projects/")) {
   $_.Quota = $quotaTemplate;
}
```

Comment: HI Dave I am getting the following error can you help me........... Method invocation failed because                     [System.String] doesn't contain a method named 'ToLowerCase'.
At C:\Users\mosssqlservicet\Desktop\Test PowershellScripts\SetQoutaforSC.ps1:29 char:40
+    if ($_.ServerRelativeUrl.ToLowerCase <<<< ().StartsWith("/communities/")) {
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ToLowerCase:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be just `.ToLower()`

Answer (score 3):

Replace the bottom two lines with something like:

```
get-spwebapplication $WebApplicationUrl | 
  Get-spsite -limit all | 
  Where-Object {$_.ServerRelativeUrl.StartsWith("/projects/")} |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Quota = $quotaTemplate }
```